# Unable to install laravel using composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I installed composer successfully.

Now i am trying to install `laravel` using this command `composer global require "laravel/installer"` in command prompt but i can't able to install `laravel`.

This show me something like below image.

[image]

When i use `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` in command prompt then it will show me something like below image.

[image]
What should i do? any suggestion?

Comment: the other way is better: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog

Comment: Try this method Step 1) clone [Laravel Repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) or download zip will also work 2) go to the directory 3) execute composer install done...

Comment: I've seen this few times on github issues for composer repo. Update composer to last version. Are using proxy/vpn? Could you try run it with '-vvv' for more verbose output?

Comment: @AkshayKhale Thanks, I tried this but not understand, can you please explain in brief with answer?

Comment: @AkshayKhale my php version is  PHP 5.6.28 and laravel requirement is PHP >= 5.6.4 . this may cause problem to install laravel?

Comment: @AkshayKhale please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337917/i-can-not-able-to-install-laravel

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused due to many possible reasons, like:

1. You are behind the firewall and firewall block it.
2. Your internet is too slow. (Hope it is not the case)
3. You are using VPN or PROXY. (Not all VPN causes this error.)
4. You have both ipv4 and ipv6 enabled (Not sure about this case.)

I cannot confirm about the main reason that is caused for you to not being able to create project from composer but you could try some methods like:

1. Changing to different ISP.
2. Try running `composer -vvv`: This helps to check what actually is doing behind the scene and helps in further more debug.
3. Try updating `composer` to latest version.
4. Try creating some older version of Laravel or any other packages

   `composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"`
5. Try using some VPN.

This is only for testing and doesn't have fully confirmed solution.

If there is any other reason we could edit this solution.

Answer (score -2):

If are installing the composer make sure that,you must have to set environment variable for PHP. If your using xampp control panel ->go to xampp installed path->PHP. Then copy location and set in the environment location.Then try to install composer.